# Opencart проверка купленного шаблона

Tags: opencart

Добрый день! Куплен шаблон под Opencart. Есть подозрение на пересылку клиентов, вредоносный код, доступ к сайту и ссылки на другие сайты. Как можно это проверить, есть ли алгоритм?

Comment: Где вы покупали шаблон? Откуда подозрения? Опишите в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто, у вас на сайте должен быть счётчик от Яндекс метрики или Гугл Аналитикс. Если нет то добавьте, данные получите после 24 часов после добавления кода отслеживания,  там подробная инфа по навигаций пользователей, откуда пришли и куда ушли и т.д.

А по поводу вредоносного кода тут немного сложней нужно проверять файлы, ну в конце концов самй просмотрите внешне сайт есть ли какие сылки перенаправляющие на другие сайты.